# How to fire query between two variables range?

Tags: database

How to fire query between two variables range?

```
SELECT * from table where range_from>="0.09" and range_to<="0.09" and id = "158"
```

This is not giving right result.

Comment: both variable range are same, you have to define different range for getting right result

Comment: In database, range_from is 0.05 and range_to is 0.15. I am getting value is 0.09.  I want to fire query where 0.09 is between 0.05 and 0.15  I think somewhere I have gone wrong.

Comment: you want to fire query with  between

Comment: yes, I think i.e is the last option. Since I have many range.

Comment: but you can set between query for only one column

Comment: @rakesh How to set??

Comment: try this : select * from *table_name* where range_from >= 0.09 and range_to <= 0.09 and id = 158

Comment: @Abdul i tried but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set between query for column like this,

you can set column name as per your table column and tablename is your tablename.

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename WHERE (column_name BETWEEN 0.05 AND 0.15)
AND id=158;
```

Comment: But I have ranges like  0 to 0.05  0.06 to 0.1  0.1 to 0.5  0.5 to 1.......

Comment: you can set dynamic value based on forloop inside query

Comment: you can also use range(0,2,0.5) function of php for your case

Comment: I have a table where ranges are defined. From that table I have to fetch the record.

Comment: I removed table and used for loop